# Dynamic Value - Copy Category & Feature and Paste in other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a list of categories and features in "Data copy"

I want to get a list as seen in "Data paste"

I have been trying to change a script that I worked with before, since it works off the same basics, but I couldn't get it to work.

Example file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vMDRMe0n54k81lf1R9QL5XWg6yPOHZYTXQNSXlnq5P4/edit#gid=752140290

The Data copy is the original data, which is also dynamically changing depending on the product

The Data paste is how it should be organized.

The App Script used right now:

```
function copyInfo() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data copy");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data paste");
  var values = copySheet.getRange("A1:Z1" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[7] == check).map(r => [4,6,10,15].map(e => r[e - 1]));
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

  var check = "Private/White Label"; // This is from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data copy");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data paste");
  var values = copySheet.getRange("A2:Z" + copySheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[8] == check).map(r => [4,6,10,15].map(e => r[e - 1]));
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing it twice.  First `"A1:Z1" + copySheet.getLastRow()`  and then `"A2:Z" + copySheet.getLastRow()`.  And they are stacked after each other.

Comment: I am an app script novice. So I dont have any clue either.

Comment: Then what do you want to do?

Comment: We have a list of categories and features in "Data copy"

I want to get a list as seen in "Data paste"

Comment: Only columns A and B?

Comment: What have you tried so far in this specific scenario? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. I understand you want to use this script for the shared sheet. Can you share an example where you have tried that script before? In the script you're filtering by criteria "Private/White Label" and I don't see that value anywhere in the provided sheet. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.